# Paypal payment processor not working

Tags: paypal

This is our form http://manningmedia.net/glos/test/ , built under contribution page by loading user profile on it, it must be redirecting to standard paypal website after submitting, but it is redirecting to thankyou page only. We have already set payment processor as "standard  paypal" and enabled contribute component also, but stil it is not working, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your contribution page configuration for amount tab. May be you have unchecked the Execute real- real time monetary transaction.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it is already checked in my settings, here is the screenshot of all settings : 1) https://www.diigo.com/item/image/5hk74/e5k8 , 2) https://www.diigo.com/item/image/5hk74/shr4, 3) https://www.diigo.com/item/image/5hk74/3ytk, 4) https://www.diigo.com/item/image/5hk74/09rq , is anything else you want ? please help to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Make your payment processor as default payment processor.

Comment: Did you make any changes to remove confirmation page? As I have checked your page it doesn't go to confirmation page. If yes then remove that changes and test it again.

Comment: Also there is below warning on your page.

Warning Some of the profile fields cannot be configured for this page.

Just remove  the the profile and check(just for testing).

Comment: You are right, I have unchecked confirmation page and removed profile (https://www.diigo.com/item/image/5hk74/h0ka), now it is redirecting to paypal with warning "The seller accepts encrypted website payments only. You cannot pay the seller through un-encrypted buttons. Please contact your seller for more details.", now how will I show other fields (i.e. First name, last name, phone etc.) without profile, because if we setup profile it is not redirecting to paypal, I can give you user/pass to check this, just send me blank email on this mail id testwts017@gmail.com

Comment: Check your email.

Comment: You can use the profile but you need to checked the confirmation page option.